# How to write LMM in an exact solution form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

`The question requires me to apply

> $x_{n+2}-2x_{n+1}+x_{n} = h(f_{n+1}-f_{n})$

into the IVP $x'(t)=-x(t)$ with $x(0) = 1$ and the starting value $x_0$= $x_1$ =$1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the right side of your recursion equation. With that you get
$$
x_{n+2}-2x_{n+1}+x_n=h(x_n-x_{n+1})\\
(r-1)^2=-h(r-1)\\
(r-1)(r-1+h)=0
$$
so that you get indeed the roots $r=1$ and $r=1-h$.

---

This exercise tells you that $x_1$ should at least be order 2 accurate.

---

PS: You can also show directly that $x_n=x_0$ is a constant sequence, as if $x_k=x_0$ for $k<n$ then 
$$
x_n=2x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}+h(f(x_{n-1})-f(x_{n-2}))=2x_0-x_0+h(f(x_0)-f(x_0))=x_0.
$$

Comment: tks!! so now i found A=1 and B=0, $x_n=1$.
Can I say that ()-  -> 0 as h->0 so it is convergent?

Comment: No, of course not. The numerical sequence is constant $1$ while the exact solution is a falling exponential. If $x_1$ is determined by the Euler step, then you get convergence as the sequence is the one of the explicit Euler method. This is because the LMM is the difference of two Euler steps.

Comment: i am a bit confused. Now i have +(1−ℎ)^ . and A=1, B=0, so =1. What does this really mean? is that mean =1 and i still need to find x(tn) for the prove of convergence?]

Comment: Why do you think you could get convergence? $x(t)=e^{-t}$ is obviously not constant.

Comment: @Brad Please use $ and underscores, `$x_n=A+B(1-h)^n$` gives $x_n=A+B(1-h)^n$.

Comment: so in which way can i prove that it is convergent? I am so confused with $x_n$ and $x(t_n)$... am i right if $x_n$ is equal to 1? then what is $x(t_n)$??

Comment: In no way can you prove convergence for this method while setting $x_1=x_0$.

Comment: I am sorry i typed it wrong, i mean it what way can i prove that it is not convergent by comparing $x_n$ and $x(t_n)$. Am I right if $x_n$ is 1 now? then what is $x(t_n)$??

Comment: As said before, $x(t_n)=\exp(-t_n)$. And yes, $x_n=1$ independent of $h$.

Comment: understood, tks so much!